# What is the most efficient way of adding new variables to a large function with many function calls within?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a large window that has an extremely large function call(~2.5k lines).  I am curious as how would be the most efficient way to handle the need to add ~5 variables that is to be used throughout the function, but also passed between many different functions within the same large function.

Do I update all the function calls within the large function and add a `ByVal` of the new variables with all the functions that use these new variables or take the easy way out and make global variables for all of them?  I was told that too many global variables harm overall performance, not to mention it gets harder and harder to read the more you add.

I could create a new class, create a public List, Dictionary, Array to hold all of the variables I will be using, but I'm just not sure what the best way to handle this scenario is, or if it even matters as long as it works.

Comment: Is the data in the 5 variables all related, such as first name, last name, address, city, state, and zip?  If yes, then following object oriented principles you would create a structure or class for them.

Comment: A single function that is 2500 lines long doesnt sound like it is focused.  Something that long with that many vars sounds like maybe it should itself be some sort of helper class (based only on the non specific info provided)

Comment: If all the functions need the same variable, then these should've been in a class. Maybe give us an example. Based on the way you describe it, it looks a bit like a mess.

Comment: Words cannot describe how much of a mess this is.  I guess only the original large function will use the new variables but the variables get set in other function calls within that large function, so instead of having to call a function to set the variable, maybe a Class would be easiest to deal with while keeping the code easily readable and not impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I like to do when handling large amounts of repetitive Code is using the "Search and Replace" Feature. This is very useful and Time saving, especially when you have to insert the same piece of code over and over again.

**Example**

Lets say, you have a few hundred Functions that look something like this:

```
Public Function Foo(bar As String) As String
    ....
End Function
Public Function SomeFunction(SomeVariable As String) As String
    ....
End Function
```

To use this Feature in Visual Studio 2013; (Probably older Versions too ;D)

1. "Ctrl + F"
2. Insert `As String)` in the "Search" Tab
3. Insert `As String, ByVal FooBar As Integer)` i the "Replace" Section
4. Replace

Now, obviously this has some downsides, you have to cheack that only the code sections you wanted to edit are selected, otherwise it will get really, really nasty.